# Firebase dynamic links with variable parameters

Tags: swift, xcode, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I need to implement dynamic links so that we can track campaigns more effectively. One key requirement is to be able to retain UTMs for analysis, hence why we have decided to go with dynamic links.

However, I'm having difficulty understanding how to implement this when parameters in the long link may vary.

For example, let's say we have a whole line of products which belong to a specific campaign run by a third party. I want the user to be directed to the correct location for a given product code and retain the UTMs.

So let's say my short dynamic link is:

```
https://testname.page.link/spectest
```

And the long link:

```
https://testname/?link=https://testname/products/Saint-Laurent-Logo-woven-faux-raffia-cross-body-bag-1554395&isi=966121224&ibi=com.testname.testname-uk-dev&utm_campaign=Dave's+Sale&utm_medium=clc&utm_source=DaveCo
```

So, if I tap on the short link above it takes me to the location and retains the params. For example here is the link handling logic in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        Adjust.appWillOpen(userActivity.webpageURL!)
    }
    let canContinue = ActivityManager.application(application, continue: userActivity)

    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { dynamicLink, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            }
        }

        if linkHandled {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    return canContinue
}

func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
    guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
        return
    }

    print("*** Link launched: \(dynamicLink)")
    print("*** UTMs: \(dynamicLink.utmParametersDictionary)")
    StartupManager.shared.launchLinkIfApplicable(url.absoluteString)
}
```

When I tap on this link it takes me to the correct place in the app and indeed the console prints out the link and the UTMs. Now, if I navigate instead to the long link, the UTMs are empty.

What I thought I could do is put the link to any product in the dynamic link itself within the console, but then replace e.g. the product code for another and still be directed to the new product and retain the UTMs. Whilst the redirection works the UTM dictionary is empty.